# umbraco show different web page from my url. Not iframe

Tags: iis, umbraco

I have to webpages on same server, IIS.
I would like that the frontpage on the first will show the frontpage from the second; but the URL should not be changed.

- domain1.com -> show front page as normal
- domain1.com/subpage -> show subpage as normal
- domain2.com -> load front page from **domain1.com** (not in iframe)
- domain2.com/subpage -> show subpage as normal

Can this be done in Umbraco?
If not can it be done on the webserver (MS)?

Iframe is no good. And rebuilding frontpage is not the preferred solution.

BR. Anders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to write some code on the domain2.com homepage using the 'HttpWebRequest' API so that when someone visits domain2.com, this could download the HTML from domain1 and return it to the user.

(nothing to do with umbraco, but could work within umbraco.)

There may be a simpler way but this solution will work even if the sites are on different servers.
There will be lots of issues with links unless the underlying urls are all the same.

Comment: Thanks. That would work here since links on both pages are absolut due to this linking back and forth.